# How did MILAN ATGMs make their way to Afghanistan during the Soviet invasion?

Tags: military, afghanistan

Various sources mentions rather briefly that the mujaheddin used [MILAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MILAN) ATGMs against the Soviets.

Who supplied these exactly? Were they e.g. from French or UK stocks? And were the US intermediaries for these deliveries, or just the Pakistani and/or Saudis?

---

Sources consulted:

> MILAN missile systems were among the numerous weapons sent to the Mujahideen in Afghanistan in the 1980s by the United States to combat Soviet troops.[9] *[Wikipedia:Afghanistan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MILAN#Afghanistan)*

Questionable it was this simple as the MILAN is not made in the US nor acquired by the US Army. Cited source "[9]" is dead link and besides it's a "Small Arms Problem in Central Asia" publication, which I suspect isn't a detailed history anyhow. I've actually managed to locate the publication cited. It says:

> The flow of small arms to Afghanistan did not end after the Soviet
> forces withdrew from the country in February 1989. Just before the
> withdrawal, the United States increased its arms supplies to Afghanistan
> to ensure that the Soviet decision to leave would hold. The United States
> provided the mujaheddin, for example, with Stingers and Milan anti-tank
> missiles, and continued to support the Afghan guerrillas in their fight
> against the pro-Soviet Kabul regime headed by President Muhammad
> Najibullah.

- [Wikipedia:Operation_Cyclone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Cyclone) doesn't mention Milans.
- [Wikipedia:AfghanWarHeavyWeapons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_equipment_used_by_mujahideen_during_Soviet%E2%80%93Afghan_War#Heavy_weapons)

gives as 160 the number of Milan launchers passed to the mujaheddin. The book cited in support (Isby D.C., *War in a distant country, Afghanistan : invasion and resistance*) isn't more detailed than that. It contains a brief inventory of mujaheddin arsenal, but not how they got them.  The book page number cited on Wikipedia is totally off, gives 42, but should be 112, where the book just says

> By early 1988, there were reports that the Resistance had received 160 European-designed Milan anti-tank guided missile-launchers, along with training for gunners. These proved effective in action throughout 1988.

And that's all the coverage given to this issue. If the quantity stated in that book is correct, it's a pretty sizable number, comparable e.g. to the official stockpiles of such missiles of some smaller countries (using Wikipedia numbers again).

Comment: [Wikipedia says they were supplied by the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MILAN#Afghanistan)

Comment: @KillingTime: yeah, but that's pretty vague as the US doesn't manufacture these, nor do they normally buy them.

Comment: Looking at the distribution of MILAN in the world, it seems pretty simple for the US or the Pakistani to get some

Comment: @totalMongot: 160 launchers (number of missiles not specified) is pretty sizeable though. It's pretty much the entire arsenal of such missiles of one of these smaller countries.

Comment: @Fizz You're right, so there might have been a specific delivery to anyone who sent them later in Afghanistan.

Comment: Side remark: why would Milan ATGM be used instead of American-made TOW? Because they are much lighter with still enough range for the mountain warfare of Afghanistan

Comment: @totalMongot: yeah, probably that. You can see a lot of footage of Ukrainians carrying NLAWs nowadays, but hardly any carrying Javelins. Probably for the same reason. According to Wikipedia, there were some 80 TOW launchers sent to the mujahedeen too though.

Comment: @Fizz Not sure, was it a joke?^^ Because in Ukraine, the reason for NLAW vs Javelin is price and training. Every ukrainian would use a Javelin had they enough of them (maybe urban fight is exception)

Comment: @MCW: see update.

Comment: @Fizz the US purchased over the years many foreign weapons systems and vehicles, both for its own use and for distribution to client states and organisations. Milan was portable, easy to use, and available whereas no comparable US built system existed at the time (there was a major gap between the LAW and the TOW in the US arsenal).

Comment: @totalMongot TOW is a heavy system that requires extensive training to use effectively. Milan you can transport several on a horse, TOW you need a truck or several horses for a single one.

Comment: @jwenting Thanks for hindsight,and you're right TOW is heavy

Answer (score 3):

The [SIPRI Yearbook for 1989](https://www.sipri.org/sites/default/files/SIPRI%20Yearbook%201989.pdf) (page 244) lists 140 MILANs as delivered in 1988; they are in the table as from France but it explicitly notes "supplier country uncertain".

(It is unclear if it means missiles or launchers - the entries for some other countries give the number of *missiles* in this column, and the number of launchers as a comment.)

There are no deliveries mentioned in the 1990-93 Yearbooks, or 1980-88; that batch seems to be the only one that was publicly discussed at the time. Interestingly - while it says nothing about MILAN - the 1987 one mentions British Blowpipe SAMs as being "paid for by the USA and supplied via Nigeria", which gives a hint as to the complicated route some weapons may have taken.